# Set part of cookie in express request

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have set up a request using express which has the following options:

```
const options = {
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  json: true,
  headers: {
    'cookie': SESSION_COOKIE_NAME + '=' + sessionId
  }
};
```

This works well, however the problem is that this sets the entire cookie to the result of `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME + '=' + sessionId`. If I want to simply set the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` "property" of the cookie how would I go about doing that?

Note: `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` is simply an environment variable which points to the string of this actual cookie name.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set cookies in `express` using the following snippet:

> res.cookie('cookieName', cookieValue, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly:
>   true });

I don't see any reason you manually modifying the cookie string when express helps you with that.

See documentation: [`res.cookie`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)